# Passing and using a parameter in Google Apps Script Web App

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Imagine this scenario. I have a google spreadsheet with various columns. The first column is called ID. This spreadsheet is updated from a Google Calendar (using Google Apps script and the Google Calendar API) on a timer basis (e.g. every 5 minutes). The ID identifies the calendar entry. The user creating the entry, at the point of the record being appended to the spreadsheet, should receive an email with a link to a form, with the ID being passed as parameter. This form consists of some further advanced details not offered by the Google Calendar out-of-the-box functionality. The user will then fill in the form, and the relevant row should be updated in the spreadsheet according to the user's selection.

My plan is to create an Apps Script project within the Google Spreadsheet, and load an HTML page using the Html Service. On submitting of the form, the user selection will be used in the App script to update the Google spreadsheet. What I cannot figure out is the logic behind passing the ID (reference) to the spreadsheet row to be updated. Can it be done? In a normal HTML scenario, I would append a parameter to the URL dynamically, and then use Javascript to extract the parameter from the query string. In the case of a deployed web app, I have no idea what to do.

```
function doGet() {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
    return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function updateSpreadsheet(input1, input2) {
    return "ok";
}
```

The deployed app script in a web app link would look something like:

```
https://script.google.com/a/domain.com/macros/s/Adlksjflf09_LEg8kdlf9/exec?ID=1
```

where ID = 1 refers to the ID of the calendar as recorded within the Google Spreadsheet.

The doGet() function would be used to retrieve the ID and use it in the updateSpreadsheet() function to update the relevant record in the spreadsheet (implementation to update the spreadsheet still to be done).

Any idea how to pass the parameter to the web app and actually use it? Furthermore, if my reasoning is wrong or there is a better way about it kindly let me know ! Thanks for your help, in advance.

Comment: The `e` event parameter will log an object with the key specified in the URL. So, by passing `?ID=1`, you can use `doGet(e) { Logger.log(e.parameters) }` and extract the params for use in other functions. Event params for web apps are [documented here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)

Comment: Oh! I was quite on the right lines, I must say! Had not run into that part of the documentation, perhaps I was searching for the wrong keywords. Would a global variable work in this scenario? Or would the ID need to be passed to the HTML page and back to the app script, to be used in the updateSpreadsheet() method?

Comment: No, you can pass it right from `doGet` to another `.gs` function before returning updating the client.

Comment: @Brian I think this would lock the UI of the web app until all server-side functions have finished executing. Could be an issue for larger apps. I think the better way is to immediately serve the page using doGet() and asynchronously call the .gs functions from the client using google.script.run  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication  You can then pass the returned value to the withSuccessHandler() function and update the UI dynamically.

Comment: @AntonDementiev Sure, for larger apps you'd definitely want to take that approach. But, it isn't _required_.

Comment: @Brian I do not understand the steps to be taken. How is the value of the ID retained in the app script until the user has the chance to fill in the form and submit, if the ID is not passed to the HTML at all? Strictly speaking I won't need the ID in the HTML, only the app script, but I want to be able to use it in the updateSpreadsheet() method when the HTML form submits into it.

Comment: @AntonDementiev - does your method entail passing the ID to the HTML and pass it back to the app script?

Comment: You may use user-specific Cache to persist values in Google Apps Script https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/ When a user fills out the form, you simply call the server side function and pull the value from cache storage via Cache.getUserCache().getKey(key); Alternatively, you can pass variables to HTML using the approach described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466291/pass-google-script-value-to-html/50466703#50466703