# Google Scripts - Using dynamic Javascript variables in HTML.index file

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Scripts for dynamic sendMail functions.  Once a row is highlighted, relevant data points are filled into an email message and sent on.  This email sent is very basic (plain text only) however and I would like to use HTML to spruce it up to look more professional.  I have added a HTML.index file within and the respective HTML code, I have referenced the HTML file from the .gs (javascript) file and it works and sends emails, however, I want to know how to incorporate the var (variables) from the .gs (javascript) file, directly into the HTML.index file.  Variables are dynamic and determined already by coding in the .gs (javascript) file.  What I am looking for is essentially to bring those dynamic values into the nicer looking html email that is sent out.

I have searched the internet and found to use

```
<?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
```

in the HTML.index file, where JavaScript is the name of the .gs (javascript) file.  However, I believe this incorporates the ENTIRE file, whereas I only want to input the respective var (variable) desired.

Javascript code (.gs)

```
function Test11() { //Testing script emails with html
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ActiveRow = ss.getActiveRange().getRow() - 1;
var dataRange = ss.getRange("A:AD");
var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
var rowData = data[ActiveRow];
var emailAddress = rowData[29]; //email OK
var ApptStatus = rowData[6]; //Appt Status OK
var message2 = rowData[9]; //Name
var message3 = rowData[10]; //Language
var message4 = rowData[11]; //Date
var message5 = rowData[12]; //Time
var message6 = rowData[13]; //Type
var message7 = rowData[14]; //Notes
var message8 = rowData[15]; //Fac Name
var message9 = rowData[16]; //Address
var message10 = rowData[17]; //City
var FacState = rowData[21]; //State
var message11 = rowData[18]; //Zip
var message12 = rowData[19]; //Phone
var message13 = rowData[20]; //Service
var ccmsg = {cc: 'email@domain.com'}
var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index') //htmlOutput 
connects index.html file, getContent shows content but not in html
var message = htmlOutput.getContent() // WORKS
var Amessage = INSERT MESSAGE HERE //original plain text
var subject = 'TEST ONLY - please IGNORE: ' + message2 + ' (' + message4 + ' 
at ' + message5 + ' in ' + message10 + ')';
MailApp.sendEmail('email@domain.com', subject, message, 
{'htmlBody':message});
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">

HTML CODING (not included as its 700+ lines)

Just a sample of my ideal outcome
Confirmation of your appointment at 'message4' (DATE FROM GS 
file) at 'message5' (TIME FROM GS FILE), etc.

MORE HTML CODING

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass google script value to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50466291/pass-google-script-value-to-html)

Comment: I have reviewed the other post and added to .gs

    `var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
    var m2html = message2
    htmlTemplate.m2html = message2`

I have also added to the html file

    `<input type="text" name="m2html" id="m2html" value="<?!= m2html ?>">`

I am still missing some key steps that I am unsure of.

Comment: Which steps you are unsure of? Please rephrase your post to make it an actual question. You could start by using the code samples from Google's documentation as a quick start and verify that it works, then change your code accordingly. Looking at your code snippet, it seems that you haven't read the section on templated HTML and scriptlets in GAS docs.

Comment: The proposed code does not work.  It shows a fillable text box with "text" prefilled in the email sent.  It does not pull the relevant data needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing for you to do is to add placeholders in your HTML and then replace them before sending the email.

So your index.html file would like something the following with the placeholders `{message4}` and `{message5}`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Confirmation of your appointment at {message4} at {message5}. Again, {message4} at {message5}.
  </body>
</html>
```

In your .gs file, you convert the HTML to a string, replace the values, and send the email. Importantly, this works because the `htmlBody` advanced parameter [expects a string](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options).

```
function sendConfirmationEmail() {
  var message4 = "Date";
  var message5 = "Time";

  var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index") // Generate the HTML
  .getContent(); // Convert it to a string

  var message = htmlTemplate.replace(/{message4}/g, message4) // Use regex with global flag to replace all instances
  .replace(/{message5}/g, message5); // You can chain the .replace() methods

  MailApp.sendEmail("email@example.com", "subject", plainTextBody, {"htmlBody": message});
}
```

Your output, if you did `Logger.log(message)`, would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Confirmation of your appointment at Date at Time. Again, Date at Time.
  </body>
</html>
```

I do highly recommend that you use more descriptive variable names. For example, instead of `message4`, just call it `date` or `appointmentDate`.

Comment: I like the idea of using the placeholders.  However, when I put in the above code, I am receiving the following error: TypeError: Cannot find function replace in object HtmlTemplate.  I also am not sure about using var message4 = "Date"; because the message4 is dynamic data pulled from a spreadsheet, the Date is different depending upon which row in the spreadsheet is selected.

Comment: Thank you, this worked beautifully.  I made a couple changes:   `var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index') //htmlOutput connects index.html file
    var msg = htmlOutput.getContent() //gets content from html file
    var message = msg.replace(/{PTname}/g, PTname) //replaces placeholder of html file to variable above`